# In C++ is there a way to print char* from different memory locations?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if the question makes too much sense, so I'll try to show an example:

Imagine I had a string at memory location `&s` (not null terminated) and another string at memory location `z` (null terminated).

```
char s[4]; s[0] = 'a'; s[1] = 'a'; s[2] = 'a'; s[3] = 'a';
char *z = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
z[0] = 'a'; z[1] = 'a'; z[2] = 'a'; z[3] = '\0';
char *y = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
y[0] = 'a'; y[1] = 'a'; y[2] = 'a'; y[3] = '\0';
```

Is there a way to represent a string, `u`, that is the concatenation of `s` and `z` and another string, `v`, that is the concatenation of `s` and `y` without having to duplicate `s`?

I know that it's not going to be very fast at reading, but it will certainly save more memory especially with the number of repeats to be expected. Since the value of `s` may change separately from `z` and `y` and the changes should appear in `z` and `v`, it would certainly be more efficient to do it without cloning `s` if it were possible.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to create your own class that manages these `jumps` in the strings.

Comment: Are you making this program for embed system, if not, then forget about the memory usage.

Comment: BTW, `malloc` is more C than C++...

Comment: This is not for an embed system, but given 100000+ repeats, it's rather wasteful on memory. Without storing any of these string, I use about 70MB RAM and with storing these strings, it's closer to 270MB.

Comment: @Jarod42 is there a better way to allocate in C++? There seems to be no problem compiling with malloc in there.

Comment: @RahulManne: `new[]` (owned in `std::unique_ptr`), `std::vector<char>`, `std::array<char, 4>`, `std::string`.

Comment: I always knew new existed, but I never knew that it was more efficient! I've only learned C in school, so I'm used to malloc even more than calloc much less new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard name for the structure you want (or that I think you want) is a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) - it's like a compound sequence of strings with a unifying interface.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826431/stl-rope-when-and-where-to-use) about ropes has some discussion of them, and a link to the SGI extension.

If you pick up an existing implementation, check that the mutability of substrings works the way you want - some may implement copy-on-write instead.

Comment: +1 I couldn't remember that name. Also a trie could work in case of common prefixes (like here if I understood it correctly).

Comment: As a second thought perhaps trie isn't the best solution: it's usually used to use the strings as keys (necessary to access the real value).

Comment: I retract my previous comment then :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do what you want. You have to create your own class for representing such strings. Perhaps it would contain something like a `vector<pair<char*, size_t>>` to represent the chunks of data the string consists of.

Comment: But this won't be easily readable right? It's not like I can just use printf on a vector.

At the same time, this might be the best way to go about this.

Comment: @RahulManne if you do care about readability and the strings aren't terribly long then you should really go for a duplication and avoid unnecessary complexity

Comment: There's a perfectly standard and well-documented data structure for this, it just isn't included in the STL.

Comment: @RahulManne On what level do you mean? To outside code, it will be perfectly readable - it will be working with your own `MultiPartString` class which will have a nice interface (because you will give it a nice interface). And inside that class, that nice interface will guide the implementation and make it more easily understandable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question's title implies that you want to print this concatenated string. If that's the only use case, you could use [`writev`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/writev.html) and `iovec`. The concept is that you can write to a file descriptor in bulk from multiple data sources in one command. Just use `writev` and write to `stdout`.