# How to read a file into a vector elegantly and efficiently?

Tags: c++, performance, io, compiler-optimization, idioms

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<char> f1()
{
    ifstream fin{ "input.txt", ios::binary };
    return
    {
        istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
        istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    };
}

vector<char> f2()
{
    vector<char> coll;
    ifstream fin{ "input.txt", ios::binary };
    char buf[1024];
    while (fin.read(buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        copy(begin(buf), end(buf),
            back_inserter(coll));
    }

    copy(begin(buf), begin(buf) + fin.gcount(),
        back_inserter(coll));

    return coll;
}

int main()
{
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

Obviously, `f1()` is more concise than `f2()`; so I prefer `f1()` to `f2()`. However, I worry that `f1()` is less efficient than `f2()`.

So, my question is:

Will the mainstream C++ compilers optimize `f1()` to make it as fast as `f2()`?

**Update:**

I have used a file of 130M to test in release mode (Visual Studio 2015 with Clang 3.8):

`f1()` takes `1614` ms, while `f2()` takes `616` ms.

`f2()` is faster than `f1()`.

What a sad result!

Comment: Which is faster? - should be measured. One thing which comes to mind is that it would be good to `reserve` the required memory for the `vector` to avoid reallocations

Comment: Also, it may be worth considering using a rope, does not directly concern choice of input library, but anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826431/stl-rope-when-and-where-to-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked your code on my side using with `mingw482`.
Out of curiosity I've added an additional function `f3` with the following implementation:

```
inline vector<char> f3()
{
    ifstream fin{ filepath, ios::binary };
    fin.seekg (0, fin.end);
    size_t len = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg (0, fin.beg);

    vector<char> coll(len);
    fin.read(coll.data(), len);
    return coll;
}
```

I've tested using a file `~90M` long. For my platform the results were a bit different than for you.

- f1() ~850ms
- f2() ~600ms
- f3() ~70ms

The results were calculated as mean of 10 consecutive file reads.

The `f3` function takes the least time since at `vector<char> coll(len);` it has all the required memory allocated and no further reallocations need to be done. As to the [back_inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/) it requires the type to have `push_back` member function. Which for vector does the reallocation when `capacity` is exceeded. As described in docs:

> **push_back**
>
> This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an
>   automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if-
>   the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.

Among `f1` and `f2` implementations the latter is slightly faster although both use the `back_inserter`. The `f2` is probably faster since it reads the file in chunks which allows some buffering to take place.

Comment: My observation using this approach is that, yes the memory for coll is updated, but vector container is not aware of any of the changes. if you ask that vector its size, it will report zero.

Answer (score -1):

If smaller than some GB you can read all at once:

```
#include "sys/stat.h"
        ....

char* buf;
FILE* fin;
filename="myfile.cgt";
#ifdef WIN32
   struct stat st;
  if (stat(filename, &st) == -1) return 0;
#else
    struct _stat st;
if (_stat(filename, &st) == -1) return 0;
#endif
    fin = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fin) return 0;
    buf = (char*)malloc(st.st_size);
    if (!buf) {fclose(fin); return 0;}
    fread(buf, st.st_size, 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);
```

No need to say you should use "new" in C++ not malloc()